# Using 'this' and a JQuery function inside object callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, this

I have created an object, and am having trouble updating an element via that callback.  Here is some brief example code:

```
function myObj() {
    LINK_ID = '';
    PREFIX = '';
};

myObj.prototype.init = function(config)
{
    LINK_ID = config.link_id;
    PREFIX = config.prefix;

    $(this.LINK_ID).click($.proxy(this, 'swapState'));
};

myObj.prototype.swapState = function()
{
    $(this.PREFIX).toggleclass(this.PREFIX + "_toggled");  // Errors here
};

var m = new MyObj();
m.init({link_id: "#linky", prefix: "#mydiv"});
```

I am getting an 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' error on the line featuring the toggleclass.  I can see the value of this.PREFIX within the scope of that function, but for some reason, it won't let me call toggleclass.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `LINK_ID` and `PREFIX` variables are being set as ***global*** variables!

Comment: `toggleClass` has a capital `C`.  Also, `'#mydiv_toggled'` is not a valid class name.

Comment: Gah!  That was it Rocket.  Thanks.  I copied this code from somewhere else, and didn't think to check the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

`$(this.PREFIX).toggleClass(this.PREFIX + "_toggled");`

and, make sure you have the `xxx_toggled` classes defined.

Comment: There's so much more wrong with the code than just that.

Comment: Yes, but the cause of the specific error was the question.